# Why do some of my lvm partitions have "-real" appended to their names?

Tags: partition, lvm

In the /dev/mapper directory I can see my lvm partitions, but then I'll see some other ones with the same names, but with "-real" appended to them.

What's that about?

Answer (score 2):

Those are created automatically when you make LVM snapshots.  See [this blog posting](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/how-lvm-does-snapshots/) for some details on how the snapshot process works.